# Reference request: Real analysis with infinity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

While studying measure theory, one encounters inevitably the extended real numbers $\overline{\mathbb{R}} := \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, + \infty\}$.

I would like a book/reference that properly defines doing analysis with this stuff.

(1) For example, let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup\{+\infty\}$.

Then, it is intuitively clear that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$ when there is $m \geq 1 $ s.t. $a_m = +\infty$.

I want a book that defines what $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ means where one of the terms can be infinity. Is this done by putting a metric on the extended real numbers? Is this done by declaring something like $a + \infty = \infty$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$? The book should definitely answer these questions.

(2) More general, the book should define what $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ means where  $(a_n)$ is a sequence of extended real numbers (i.e. one of the terms can be infinity).

Comment: For (2) you just put the order topology on $\overline{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: I'm looking for a reference that answers all those questions.

Comment: There's a brief discussion of extended real numbers in Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_

Comment: Also in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*

Comment: Isn’t this in every analysis book?

Comment: Name 1 analysis book in which this is (including page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berberian's book [*Fundamentals of real analysis*](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Real_Analysis.html?id=dBvnBwAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y) defines

- $a+\infty$ in [page 74](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=MzQ6JA6SiHYC&pg=PA74&dq=The+sum+x+%2B+y+for+elements+of+R+is+partially+extended+to+R+by+the+following+conventions:&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCgM_M76TgAhUnLLkGHZMzBmMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20sum%20x%20%2B%20y%20for%20elements%20of%20R%20is%20partially%20extended%20to%20R%20by%20the%20following%20conventions%3A&f=false).
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ where one of the terms can be infinity in [page 76](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=MzQ6JA6SiHYC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=With+%5E2+ai+%3C+%2Boo+as+in+the+preceding+theorem,+nothing+essential+is+lost+by+replacing+the+index+set+I+by+the+set+%7Bi+%E2%82%AC+I+:+a%C2%BB+%3E+0+%7D.+For+the+denumerable+index+set+P+%3D+%7B1,2,3,...%7D+an+alternate+notation+is+available:&source=bl&ots=fQjsOOzRlZ&sig=ACfU3U2oK22oPYnZGilflcKHi6QtKE0wEw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_0pz176TgAhX7IbkGHRv-CXQQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).
- $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ where $(a_n)$ is a sequence of extended real numbers in [page 82](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=MzQ6JA6SiHYC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22The+corollary+points+the+way+to+a+definition+of+convergence+in%22&source=bl&ots=fQjsOOyThV&sig=ACfU3U0tEwVLROFzvd3YGbHlE8EO5xIUlg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSy5Pj7KTgAhV1ILkGHbIrA9IQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20corollary%20points%20the%20way%20to%20a%20definition%20of%20convergence%20in%22&f=false).

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot by this answer. Convergence is done using limsup and liminf!